# how to save a linked list in a vector in C/C++?

Tags: c++, list, vector

I am trying to save a linked list in a vector with a while statment, the data saves correctly in the vector but the function never exit of the while statment, this is part of the code:

```
typedef struct node *contractionIndices;
contractionIndices p, head;
contractionIndices getnode();
void insafter(contractionIndices p, int indexA, int indexB, int indexR, int indexS);

p=p->sig;                                                                                                                                   
i=0;                                                                                                                                        
while(p!=NULL)                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                         
      contIndices[i*4] = p->indexA;                                                                                                           
      contIndices[i*4+1] = p->indexB;                                                                                                         
      contIndices[i*4+2] = p->indexR;                                                                                                         
      contIndices[i*4+3] = p->indexS;                                                                                                         
      printf("Contraction C (%d): (%d,%d|%d,%d) \n", i,                                                                                       
                     contIndices[i*4],                                                                                                        
                     contIndices[i*4+1],                                                                                                      
                     contIndices[i*4+2],                                                                                                      
                     contIndices[i*4+3]);                                                                                                     
      p=p->sig;                                                                                                                               
      i++;                                                                                                                                    
    }
printf("I'm out\n");
```

EDIT

this the struc

```
struct node{
  int indexA;
  int indexB;
  int indexR;
  int indexS;
  struct node *sig;
};
```

and this insertion function:

```
void insafter(contractionIndices p, int indexA, int indexB, int indexR, int indexS)
{
  contractionIndices q;
  if(p==NULL)
    printf("ERROR, list empty\n\a");
  else
    {
      q=getnode();
      q->indexA=indexA;
      q->indexB=indexB;
      q->indexR=indexR;
      q->indexS=indexS;
      q->sig=p->sig;
      p->sig=q;
      p=p->sig;
    }
}
```

Memory alloc:

```
contractionIndices getnode()
{
  contractionIndices p;
  p=(contractionIndices)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(p==NULL)
    printf("Error: insuficient memory\a\n");
  return p;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you do `p = p->sig` at the beginning? Are you omitting the first element of the list? It would also help if you post how you declared your variables.

Comment: This is a great example to use for learning a debugger.  You could put a breakpoint after `p=p->sig` and find out what it is actually pointing to.

Comment: Is p->sig a pointer to the next element in the linked list? Even if it seems so, you need to specify more details about your linked list class implementation

Comment: Your linked list maybe loops... As this is possible with a wrongly built linked list, we cannot answer the question without the full code

Comment: @RockOnRockOut I need put `p = p->sig` at the beginning because before of enter to the while statment the list is on the final of the list. @galinette yes `p->sig` is a pointer to the next element and I already edited the post with more code, thanks

Comment: ie - the last item points back to the head? Sounds like a ring to me - not a list

Comment: How do you init the first element pointed by p before the first insertion?

Comment: @user2093311 `but the function never exit of the while statment`  Well, the only reason for that is that `p` is never NULL.  It says right there in your `while` statement to only stop when `p` is NULL.

Comment: @galinette I only use the insafter function, is that my error?, how can i fix that?

Comment: @user2093311 - Where in all of that code you posted do you set any pointer to NULL?  It is a NULL pointer that stops the loop you claim keeps going forever, and I don't see where you set anything to NULL (or my eyes are going bad).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, but when I put `q->sig=NULL;` the code does not work

Comment: @user2093311 - You have to specify in detail what is meant by "does not work".  In any event, at some point, you *must* have a pointer equal to NULL, or the loop will not terminate.  That is a given, and the first place it should be NULL is when you first create the node, as my answer gave you.  If after you create the node, you mess something up to "un-nullify" the pointer, that is a different story.

Comment: ok thanks @PaulMcKenzie I already created a function for the first value with `q->sig=NULL` and the code works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You gave the following information:

**"the function never exit of the while statment"**

Since you didn't post where you set the `sig` pointer to NULL, the first place to start doing that is when you create a node here:

```
contractionIndices getnode()
{
  contractionIndices p;
  p=(contractionIndices)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(p==NULL)
    printf("Error: insuficient memory\a\n");
  memset(p, 0, sizeof(node));  // this zeros out p
  return p;
}
```

This may not fix all of your errors, but you certainly did not set the `sig` pointer to NULL on creation of a node.